# LINQ Max Grandchild

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following hierarchy of objects in Entity Framework Code First:

```
class Parent {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}

class Grandchild {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I want to retrieve a list of parents and the age of their oldest grandchild. If I have 2 parents in my database, each parent has 2 children, and each child has 2 children:

```
Parent 1
    Child 1
        Grandchild 1 - Age 10
        Grandchild 2 - Age 15
    Child 2
        Grandchild 3 - Age 3
        Grandchild 4 - Age 7
Parent 2
    Child 3
        Grandchild 5 - Age 1
        Grandchild 6 - Age 9
    Child 4
        Grandchild 7 - Age 18
        Grandchild 8 - Age 16
```

I want the query to return two objects:

```
var expected = new List<anon>
{
    new { Name = "Parent 1", MaxAge = 15 },
    new { Name = "Parent 2", MaxAge = 18 }
};
```

How can I write this in LINQ to Entities?

***Edit***
Also, is it possible to return the grandchilds name along with their age? Basically have the max age of the grandchild and who that grandchild is?

Comment: I'm assuming it's possible for a child not to have a grandchild (null)?

Comment: Also you say LINQ to Entities, but also database, I assume you've read these entities in and have stored them in a List<T> or something?

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare It is possible that a Parent would not have any children or grandchildren.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Well, I don't think it would ever be null. I think LINQ to Entities would see that there are no children and just make an empty list instead of a null list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from parent in db.Parents
select new
{
    Name = parent.Name,
    MaxAge = (
        from child in parent.Children
        from grandchild in child.Grandchildren
        select grandchild.Age)
        .Max()
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var query = from p in parents
            select
            {
              Name = p.Name,
              MaxAge = p.SelectMany(parent => parent.children)
                .SelectMany(child => child.children)
                .Max(i => i.Age)
            };
```